# Como reproducir un mp3 cada x minutos al entrar a una pagina

Tags: javascript, setinterval, mp3

Estoy haciendo un reproductor donde suenan varias músicas y quiero que cada `x` minutos, aparte del reproductor, suene una sola música sin tocar ningún botón, solo al entrar a la pagina, y en esos `x` minutos suene la música, ahora mismo solo al tocar un botón suena, pero quiero que suene en esos x minutos, y luego vuelva a sonar cada x minutos, es decir tengo que hacer un `setInterval()` pero no se donde colocarlo, adjunto mi código para que se vea mejor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    window.onload=function(){

        // creamos el objeto audio
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

        // indicamos el archivo de audio a cargar
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'mimusica.mp3');


        document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Si deseamos que inicie siempre desde el principio
            //audioElement.currentTime = 0;

            // iniciamos el audio
            audioElement.play();
        });

        document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click", function() {
            // hacemos pausa
            audioElement.pause();
        });
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Play" id="play">
    <input type="button" value="Pause" id="pause">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Quiero que suene automáticamente en `x` minutos, y luego vuelva a repetir en esos `x` minutos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como bien dices, podrías agregar al final de tu código un **[setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)**. Esta función ejecuta lo que le definas cada x tiempo en milisegundos.
En tu caso lo llamaría así:

```
setInterval(function(){audioElement.play();},30000);
```

Definimos la función q queremos q ejecute `audioElement.play();` y luego le decimos cada cuanto.

---

Si queremos dejar de ejecutar el interval basta con asignarle un id y luego detenerlo:

```
let intervalo;

intervalo = setInterval(function(){audioElement.play();},30000);

clearInterval(intervalo);
```

Si lo quieres hacer asi, no hace falta llamar al interval anteriormente, solo con definirlo y asignarlo a una variable ya anda.

---

En resumen, tu `JavaScript` quedaria algo asi:

```
<script>
  window.onload=function(){
    // creamos el objeto audio
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

    // indicamos el archivo de audio a cargar

    document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Si deseamos que inicie siempre desde el principio
        //audioElement.currentTime = 0;

        // iniciamos el audio
        audioElement.play();
    });

    document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click", function() {
        // hacemos pausa
        audioElement.pause();
    });

    //se reproduce mi archivo cada 30 segundos
    setInterval(function(){audioElement.play();},30000);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: La coloque como dijiste, en mi body asi: `<body onLoad="setInterval(function(){audioElement.play();},3000);">` y me sale : `Uncaught ReferenceError: audioElement is not defined`, algo hice mal?

Comment: Tienes q colocarlo al final del javascript, pero dentro del `onload`. Si lo pusiste antes de declarar el elemento, no lo va a reconocer

Comment: Gracias, me funciono, pero aveces me sale un par de veces el mensaje `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.` y luego de un par de veces que me salga y repita suena, es raro

Comment: mmm nunca me había salido un error asi, pero si te anda, ignóralo. Si en algun momento molesta en algo del código, googlealo, o escribeme por aqui y lo vemos juntos.

Comment: Tal vez tiene que ver con algo de la carga, por que lo estoy haciendo localmente y la musica es de una pagina que lo llamo por link, y debe haber alguna interferencia